# Required body is missing in Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to update customers info with this method
This is a classic update method where I take DTO as body and set the variables.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/updateCustomerForm/{identityNumber}")
    public String updateCustomerForm(@PathVariable("identityNumber") String identityNumber,@RequestBody CustomerDTO customer){
        customerService.updateCustomer(identityNumber,customer);
        return "redirect:/customer/showList";
    }
```

This is my thymeleaf

```
 <form th:action="@{/customer/updateCustomerForm/*{identityNumber}}" th:object="${customer}" method="put">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
    <input type="text" th:field="*{identityNumber}" placeholder="Enter identity number" class="form-control col-4 mb-4" />

    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control col-4 mb-4" />

    <input type="text" th:field="*{surname}" placeholder="Enter surname" class="form-control col-4 mb-4" />

    <input type="text" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" placeholder="Enter phone number" class="form-control col-4 mb-4" />

    <input type="text" th:field="*{salary}" placeholder="Enter salary" class="form-control col-4 mb-4" />

    <input type="text" th:field="*{age}" placeholder="Enter age" class="form-control col-4 mb-4" />

    <button class="btn btn-primary col-2" type="submit">Save</button>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{identityNumber}" />
  </form>
```

The error is required body is missing.

Can someone help with this topic?

Comment: How does your CustomerDTO.class looks like?

Comment: It contains the name,surname,phonenumber,salary and age fields. @Nemanja

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf **doesn't use JSON** so you can't use `@RequestBody` to deserilize your message, since you are not getting JSON when you submit thymeleaf form. You can use `@ModelAttribute` to avoid handling each form fields manually. Thymeleaf and Spring let you bundle all of them together using annotation I just mentioned.

So, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/updateCustomerForm/{identityNumber}")
    public String updateCustomerForm(@PathVariable("identityNumber") String identityNumber,@ModelAttribute CustomerDTO customer){
        customerService.updateCustomer(identityNumber,customer);
        return "redirect:/customer/showList";
    }
```

Shoud work as expected.
For implementation details check [this post](https://springhow.com/thymeleaf-form-handling/)

Comment: I tried it with the @ModelAttribute and the error is gone. But now it is not getting updated.

Comment: Based on your code that you posted, I can't see what the problem is. In the answer, I provided a link to the post that you can read. It describes how to implement form submission with thymeleaf and Spring. It is possible that when you render the form, you didn't add the object in the model attribute. You should have something like this in your code model.addAttribute("customer", new CustomerDTO());

Comment: Where to put this model.AddAttribute? in controller ? @Nemanja

Comment: Yes, you should put that in method which is called when returning view which contains thymeleaf form. Sometnihg like this @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String renderThymeleafForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("customer", new CustomerDTO());
    ...
  }